# remover dados repetidos no mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela chamada **`cadastro`**:
cod | nome | idade

Com os dados:

```
   COD   NOME     IDADE 
    2  | rafael  | 15
    3  | bruno   | 17
    4  | rafael  | 33
    5  | sabrina | 18
    6  | bruno   | 15
    7  | paulo   | 15
    8  | rafael  | 15
```

Notem que algum nomes se repetem, eu preciso rodar um comando no meu **mysql** para apagar todos os nome repetidos e manter apenas 1, que contenha o maior **`cod`**.

Exemplo:

tenho 3 registros com o nome  ***rafael***.

Nesse caso teria que manter apenas o `8 | rafael | 15`.

Isso é possível de ser feito?

Comment: Faz parte do escopo da pergunta as alterações na tabela para evitar que isso aconteça?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `DELETE` com `INNER JOIN` na mesma tabela, porém no `INNER JOIN` você vai trazer somente os registros onde o `cod` for menos que o da primeira tabela.

```
DELETE b FROM cadastro a
INNER JOIN cadastro b ON a.nome = b.nome AND b.cod < a.cod
```

> Faça um backup da tabela antes de executar, não tenho sua tabela aqui
>   para fazer o teste.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, vlw.

Comment: Notei uma coisa, quando rodo o comando em um banco de dados com mais de 100mil registro ele demora muito, muito mesmo. Tem alguma forma de melhorar a performasse?